# Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) not opening a new transaction in private method getting same value passed as parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using jpa entity listner class where and spring data repository . In @PreMethod update if I used `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` I am getting data from the database directly. If  I use the same **transactional annotation** over private method(**getOldEmployee**) being `called inside @PreMethod` I am not getting the data from the database rather its using the same latest session data not sure why this behaviour is happening

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
@EntityListeners({EmployeeListener.class)
public class Employee extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {

}
```

**Listener class**

```
 @Component
 public class EmployeeListner{
 
 @Autowired
 EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

  @PreUpdate
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)   //if use here I get the employee database value before updating the database
  public void preUpdateEvent(Employee employee) {
    Employee employee=getOldEmployee(employee);
  }


  private Employee getOldEmployee(Employee employee) {     //if inspite of using  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) in @PreMethod if use here I am not getting the database value rather getting latest value
    Optional<Employee> getOldEmployeeOptional =employeeRepository.findById(employee.getId());
    getOldEmployeeOptional  
  }
}
```

Comment: `@Transactional` with Spring AOP won't work. It will only work for public methods and externally called methods. This is due to proxies being used to apply AOP.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried making private method to public but applying in @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) over getOldEmployee() method doesn't work calling employeeRepository.findById(employee.getId());gives only latest value which is being passed not from database

Comment: @M.Deinum But if i apply @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)  over preUpdateEvent method it works calling employeeRepository.findById(employee.getId()); is giving me value from database

Comment: As stated that won't work either because it is an internal method call.

Answer (score 0):

Spring applies the Transactional settings only on **public** methods, in other case the settings are ignored.
From Spring documentation:

> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
> only to methods with public visibility.

Comment: I have tried made method public also but same result I am getting the same new value rather the old value which should be from database

Comment: no not in my code but if i dig down to simpleJpaRepository of spring readOnly=true mentioned there 
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID>

Comment: Anyway when using Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW it does span a new transaction (if supported by the DB) which means any error won't affect the outer transaction. Your problem is different: you JPA session has only one object (the modified one) which is in memory (or maybe flushed  to the DB but not yet committed). What you want is to use a different session to load the original value or try session.refresh (this overwrites changes made to the entity though). With Hibernate you can also evict the object and re-query (to reload from DB), I expect something similar is possible with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

It will only work for externally called methods, i.e., transaction methods should be present in another class and should be called from this class.

Meaning that the transaction method has to be public as well because we cannot call a method of another class if that method is not public.

So if you call local methods of the same class directly, Spring will not be able to do the proxy magic that is needed for Transaction functionality.